# Find all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n! = m^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Find all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that

$$1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n! = m^2$$

I'm sure answer is two couples $(1,1)$ and $(3, 3)$, but I don't know how to prove that this equation is wrong for $n > 3$.